# Uploading files to Shared drive without credentials

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to upload some files to shared Drive that was opened for me by another person. I have a small project that uploads files to my Google Drive, it was developed with credentials from json and google.apis.auth.oauth2.

But now I didn't receive any credentials, only link to the folder. It is meant that I don't need anything else.

So my question is:

- is it possible to upload something to Shared Drive without any credentials? Or they should provide me all the credentials (project_id, private_key, token etc..)?

Thank you!

Comment: Try it, see if you can upload something.

Comment: @Igor I would be happy to try, but I don't quite understand how

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file on a shared drive without signing in/logging in to an account that has access to the shared drive.

If you have access to the shared drive, you can try using your own credentials and try uploading a file and see if it will work.

You can also refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives) for more info on shared drives.

Reference:
Implementing shared drive support[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives)

Comment: I have to log in to my account, but what about uploading mechanism? If I haven't credentials, I can't do it, right?